# make javascript object global for entire page

Tags: javascript, object

I've defined the following javascript object:

```
var WealthyLaughingDuckControl = {
    users: [],
    setUsers: function(new_users) {
        this.users = new_users;
    }
};
```

I would like it to be available inside the chrome/firebug's javascript console:

```
> WealthyLaughingDuckControl
// console result goes here
```

At now, I get:

```
> ReferenceError: WealthyLaughingDuckControl is not defined
```

How can I do that?

Comment: do you have the page where we can see this?  Also please tell me you don't have that object within $(document).ready statement

Comment: Oops... It is wrapped with `$(document).ready( function() {` :/... thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove the `var` keyword, or append it to window: `window.WealthyLaughingDuckControl`

Comment: Could you please take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1470494/769384) - the author said there's no difference between var and non-var if it's declared in the global scope. I did define my variable in the global scope and in fact - with `var` it's inaccessible inside js console, and without - it's accessible. Is this answer incorrect?

Comment: Maybe you are not in the global scope when using `var`, review in the code of your actual page instead of the code you write in your editor, maybe your environment wraps any javascript code you write, what exactly is your environment? is it plain Javascript?

Comment: My env is NetBeans IDE. I don't expect it to wrap it in anything. Well, my variable was defined in the `$(document).ready( function() {` though... So it was not global, afterall (sorry...)

Answer (score 3):

Define `WealthyLaughingDuckControl` at the top level i.e. not in any function.